# Renaming core Dojo packages

Tags: javascript, dojo

When using Dojo 1.6, I can "rename" the core dojo package like so:

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
   djConfig = {
      baseUrl: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/',
      scopeMap: [
         [ 'dojo', 'myDojo' ]
      ]
   }
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (typeof dojo != 'undefined') {
      document.write("Defined: dojo: " + dojo.version + '\n');
   }
   if (typeof myDojo != 'undefined') {
      document.write("Defined: myDojo: " + myDojo.version + '\n');
   }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The above prints "Defined: myDojo: 1.6.1...".  How can I accomplish the same thing in Dojo 1.7?  Following the example [here](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-November/060003.html), I tried this test, to no avail:

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
   dojoConfig = {
      baseUrl: 'dojo/1.7.2/dojo/',
      packages: [
         { name: 'myDojo',
           location: '../dojo',
           packageMap: {
              dojo: 'myDojo'
           }
         }
      ]
   }
</script>
<script src="dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (typeof dojo != "undefined") {
      document.write("Defined: dojo: " + dojo.version + '\n');
   }
   if (typeof myDojo != "undefined") {
      document.write("Defined: myDojo: " + myDojo.version + '\n');
   }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This prints "Defined: dojo: 1.7.2...".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the remapping of globals to work when using the source version, you need to set `dojoConfig.async` to something truthy and then you need to load the `'myDojo'` package.

http://jsfiddle.net/neonstalwart/44e56/ is a working example of the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // configure dojo
    dojoConfig = {
        async: 1,
        packages: [
            {
                name: 'myDojo',
                location: '../1.7.2',
                // re-map globals to different names
                packageMap: {
                    dojo: 'myDojo'
                }
            }
        ],
        deps: ['myDojo'],
        callback: function () {
            if (typeof dojo != "undefined") {
                alert("Defined: dojo: " + dojo.version + '\n');
            }
            if (typeof myDojo != "undefined") {
                alert("Defined: myDojo: " + myDojo.version + '\n');
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/dojo/dojo/1.7.2/dojo.js"></script>
```

​

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I think I'm a good deal farther now.  However, I'm seeing different behavior depending on what 1.7.2 release I point to.  I tried your github link (simple myDojo.fadeIn() works), the Google CDN link on dojotoolkit.org (get several multipleDefine errors for same fadeIn() test), and pointing directly to a local copy I got directly from dojotoolkit.org/downloads ("myDojo.style is not a function").  I updated your example to show what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/44e56/4/

Comment: @Tommy If it's work, you should to click accept the answer :D

Comment: Well, I'm still struggling with why some 1.7.2's work and others don't, but this has definitely gotten me going in the right direction, thanks again!

Comment: the github link i've used is using a source version.  the google cdn is a built version and i suspect the version you downloaded is built as well.  that's likely your issue.  let me know if you have problem with the source version (has -src in the name) from http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/